# Compiling the Settings app from the Android Source Code

Tags: android, android-source, android-settings

Well I have always been puzzled by the android source code and how to compile it. By reading on stackoverflow and on other websites I have come to the idea that to compile it you have to pull the whole android tree and do the actual compile on linux.

I want to make some changes to the settings app from the android source code and compile it as a standalone application.

Reading and searching I came to the idea that it cannot be done since it has calls to nonpublic api. Although I have seen some posts which kind of suggested otherwise.

**Is it possible to make changes and compile the Settings app as a standalone application ?**

**If so could you give me an idea on what direction I should go ?**

Comment: To do an actual build, you do indeed need dependencies which are meant to be satisfying by checking out a complete AOSP source and letting the build system build the dependencies first (or more simply, the whole thing).  However for very small contained changes you may be able to do something by disassembling the apk, patching it, and reassembling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make changes and compile the Settings app as a standalone application ?

In AOSP you can build separate modules, so the answer is you can build it. The problem is Settings app uses services that their code is located outside Settings app so you'll have to use sources compatible with your ROM. In addition, Settings app needs system permissions so you'll have to replace the original Settings app (it's will also avoid conflicts with original app).

> If so could you give me an idea on what direction I should go

I'll move on with that direction only if you planning using a custom ROM. Then, I'll download its sources and compile Settings app. After I've validated my version is compatible with the ROM, I'll start updating Settings app with my changes.

Comment: well I thought o the first part of the settings app problem, I did not think off the system permssion problem though and to avoid the conflicts with the original Settings app.

Comment: and I am not planning on using a custom ROM unfornately.